# I want to rotate a "div" randomly, when i click a button

Tags: javascript, html

"Pijl" is the div I want to rotate randomly.
"Knop" is the button that is needed to make the div rotate.

```
var pijl = document.querySelector("#arrow");
var knop = document.querySelector("#bottom");
var spin = Math.round(Math.random() * (360));

knop.addEventListener("click", draai);
function draai(evt) {
   pijl.rotate(spin + "deg");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a div using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126432/rotate-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `rotate()` method, you need apply the css style property instead. You can refer the following question : [How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript) or [Rotate a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126432/rotate-a-div-using-javascript). Also you need to move the variable spin inside the function if you want to generate random values on each click.

```js
var pijl = document.querySelector("#arrow");
var knop = document.querySelector("#bottom");

knop.addEventListener("click", draai);

function draai(evt) {
  var spin = Math.round(Math.random() * (360));
  pijl.style.transform = 'rotate(' + spin + 'deg)';
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow" style="margin:50px;width:50px;height:20px;background:red">arrow</div>
<button id="bottom">click</button>
```

Comment: @PabloRotesSchnieders : glad to help