# Rotate Image in JavaScript with new Image()

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, rotation

I tried to rotate an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXW2.png) in javascript using the `new Image()` I tried with this:

```
this.gunner = new Image()
this.gunner.src = *url*
this.gunner.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(20deg)"
```

but the image still was like normal.

How can I do this?

Comment: which browser are you testing this?

Comment: I'm testing it in chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a div using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126432/rotate-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';
document.body.append(image);
image.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```