# How to use timer to click buttons in C#

Tags: c#, button, timer

How to use timers to trigger click button event every 3 seconds?

I'm trying to rotate 2 pictures in pictureboxes by triggering the rotate button automaticly using timer but it seems doesnt works. I never used timer before so this is my first time. Anyone know whats wrong with my code or any other code suggestion for it? Thanks

Code I'm using

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rotateRightButton_Click(null, null);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pictureBox2.Refresh();
        }
        private void timerStartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timerStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to trigger the Button? Why not just rotating the Picture with CSS like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126432/rotate-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: To "click" a button you should be using [`rotateRightButton.PerformClick()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with your code? You should create a method which rotates the picture and call that method from both `timer1_Tick` and `button_click` event handlers.

Comment: Did you set your timer interval? timer.Interval = 3000; ?

Comment: yes I've set the interval to 3000. also method to rotate the pictures and anything inside the pictures is all inside the rotate button. 
@BrOsCoRe its not only pictures there but also line drawn by coordinates so to make it simple I just want the timer to click the button.

Comment: @MatthewWatson tried that just now but still didnt work. will try again tomorrow

Comment: `rotateRightButton_Click(null, null);` who is the sender?

Comment: Did yolu try setting a debug point in timer1_tick and made sure it is hit ?

Comment: Better to create a method say `private void RotateRight() { .. }` to do the code in `rotateRightButton` so you can call that method in the `rotateRightButton` click event and in the timer's `Tick` event and elsewhere. Also, as I remember your growing project, you are handling the `Paint` event to draw images and lines, then you should call `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` method to update the drawings instead of `pictureBox1.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even possible (and more simple) with tasks

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // variable to keep track if the timer is running.
    private bool _timerRunning;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task StartTimer()
    {
        // set it to true
        _timerRunning = true;

        while (_timerRunning)
        {
            // call the rotateRightButton_Click (what you want)
            rotateRightButton_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pictureBox2.Refresh();
            // wait for 3 seconds (but don't block the GUI thread)
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    }

    private void rotateRightButton_Click(Form1 form1, EventArgs empty)
    {
       // do your thing
    }

    private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if it's already started, don't start it again.
        if (_timerRunning)
            return;

        // start it.
        await StartTimer();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stop it.
        _timerRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timer1.Interval = 3000; // set interval to 3 seconds and then call Time Elapsed event

timer1.Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;


//Event
private void Time_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
       // will be triggered in every 3 seconds
        rotateRightButton_Click(null, null);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        pictureBox2.Refresh();
 }
```

Hope this helps!